# SSL invalid security certificate with firefox only

Tags: firefox, ssl

API GET call from a website only from mozilla browser I get following error "VIP uses invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported”

tested the vip thru SLLLABS.com found out that cipher suite returned from my certificate from server is not in the preference list of mozilla - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Firefox&version=47&platform=Win%207&key=132

Is this could be the issue ? How to add the required cipher suite in the certificate, what steps to follow.

Report also indicated there is no forward secrecy and session cahcing, not sure if this causes this issue?!

SSL Lab report.
Firefox 31.3.0 ESR / Win 7  Server closed connection
Firefox 46 / Win 7  R   Server closed connection
Firefox 47 / Win 7  R   Server closed connection
Forward Secrecy No   WEAK (more info)
Session resumption (caching)    No (IDs assigned but not accepted)

Comment: there's a few gazillion vendors of SSL certs, and obviously yours isn't one that Mozilla's baked into the browser. You'll either have to install the CA's public cert, or use another ssl vendor.

Answer (score 0):

> cipher suite returned from my certificate from server is not in the preference list of mozilla - Is this could be the issue ?

No. Your error message is specifically:

> "The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported"

This specific issue is that Firefox can't build a chain back to a trusted root. Firefox uses its own root store and root program, so it differs in behavior of IE / Edge / Chrome, all of which use the Windows certificate store or OS X certificate store.

Without knowing exactly which CA issued your certificate, and what intermediates your server is set to serve, it's hard to say exactly what is wrong.

If SSL Labs says the certificate is fine, look for "incomplete chain" or "extra downloads" in orange where it displays the certificate chain. If those show, then you have an incomplete chain, which are necessary to building back to the root.

If SSL labs says your certificate isn't trusted (shows a big red 'T') then your certificate is not issued by a public CA, or SSL Labs wasn't able to find the intermediates, either.

> Report also indicated there is no forward secrecy and session cahcing, not sure if this causes this issue?!

Forward secrecy is a very good thing to have enabled but it is not the cause of this error.

Comment: SSL lab didnt say incomplete chain "Additional Certificates (if supplied) /  
Certificates provided 2 (2639 bytes) / Chain issues None". I did not say your certificate isnt trusted, it just highlights "The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers. Grade reduced to A- "  I am able to down load the certificate chain, these certs downloaded. Following is the certificate  provided 'Entrust Certification Authority - L1K'